# Magento 225 :Notice: Array to string conversion

Tags: magento2.2, save, admin-controller

When I try to create a new record in my custom module I get the below mentioned error

> Something went wrong while saving the item.Notice: Array to string
>   conversion in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Magento225/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
>   on line 3028

Admin field in Ui Component form

```
  <field name="customer_group_ids">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Customer Groups</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">customer_group_ids</item>
        </item>
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\CatalogRule\Model\Rule\CustomerGroupsOptionsProvider</item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

Error is coming form the piece of code below , when I comment out this code it works fine.

```
      if (!empty($data['customer_group_ids'])) {

            $data['customer_group_ids'] = implode(',', $data['customer_group_ids']);
        } else {
            $data['customer_group_ids'] = '';
        }
```

Below code is similar to the one mention above(customer_group_ids) and working fine and saves the records in database correctly .

```
        if (!empty($data['cmspage_ids'])) {
            $data['cmspage_ids'] = implode(',', $data['cmspage_ids']);
        }else {
            $data['cmspage_ids'] = '';
        }
```

I have both the above pieces of code in my save.php one is working fine and the other is not! What causes this issue to happen?

Output of the Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => 0
[1] => 1
[2] => 2
[3] => 3
)
```

Comment: May I know at which  point you are adding record?

Comment: there is a single table , directly from Controller\Adminhtml\Item\Save.php

Comment: @verdu did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

please check type of 
$data['customer_group_ids']

using var_dump($data['customer_group_ids']);

$data['customer_group_ids'] should be array

Comment: Error is not thrown during implode(',', $data['customer_group_ids']); this error comes when we $model->save();

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with this and try

```
if (is_array($data['customer_group_ids'])) {
    $data['customer_group_ids'] = implode(',', $data['customer_group_ids']);
}else {
    $data['customer_group_ids'] = '';
}
```

or try this

```
$yourObject->setData('customer_group_ids',implode(',', $data['customer_group_ids']));
```

As here I see something strange, your $data['customer_group_ids'] is Array but you are change the array to string and saving so not sure if you are doing this correct or not.

Comment: I tried both of your suggested solutions , but the result remains the same.